# Conditional mysqli ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE issue

Tags: mysql, sql

Anybody tell me why ts_contact_scraped is not updating using the following query,
I want if $sqlContactNumber already exists and if $sqlContactName is not equal to the corresponding name in table then update s_contact_name and ts_contact_scraped.

```
$sqlTimestamp = date('c');

$sql="INSERT INTO `" . DB_TABLE . "` (`s_contact_name`, `s_contact_number`, `ts_contact_scraped`)
VALUES ('$sqlContactName','$sqlContactNumber','$sqlTimestamp') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE s_contact_name = CASE WHEN s_contact_name <> VALUES(s_contact_name) 
THEN VALUES(s_contact_name) ELSE s_contact_name END, 
ts_contact_scraped = CASE WHEN s_contact_name <> VALUES(s_contact_name) 
THEN VALUES(ts_contact_scraped) ELSE ts_contact_scraped END";
```

Comment: I **LOVE** when I need to spend significant efforts trying to simply read the question... THAN YOU!!! Now, please post the script to create the table (which would include the creation of the indices).

Comment: thanks great FDavidov, just solved.

Answer (score 0):

It was so simple but strange for me,

just interchanged

```
ts_contact_scraped = CASE WHEN s_contact_name <> VALUES(s_contact_name) 
THEN VALUES(ts_contact_scraped) ELSE ts_contact_scraped END
```

with

```
s_contact_name = CASE WHEN s_contact_name <> VALUES(s_contact_name) 
THEN VALUES(s_contact_name) ELSE s_contact_name END
```

the final code is

```
$sqlTimestamp = date('c');
$sql="INSERT INTO `" . DB_TABLE . "` (`s_contact_name`, `s_contact_number`, `ts_contact_scraped`)
VALUES ('$sqlContactName','$sqlContactNumber','$sqlTimestamp') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
ts_contact_scraped = CASE WHEN s_contact_name <> VALUES(s_contact_name) 
THEN VALUES(ts_contact_scraped) ELSE ts_contact_scraped END,
s_contact_name = CASE WHEN s_contact_name <> VALUES(s_contact_name) 
THEN VALUES(s_contact_name) ELSE s_contact_name END";
```